# In java, can I compare child-of-child elements that share a class if their parent elements don't share a class or superclass?

Tags: java, reflection, sonarqube, composition

I'm trying to map a response object from a rest call in our sprint java application. As this is on my work computer I'll simplify and rename the issue:

I get back a rest object containing plenty of already-mapped fields and a ShapeSelect object.
The ShapeSelect object contains many kinds of specific shape objects that do not inherit from a common class, IE:

```
TriangleObject t;
SquareObject s;
PentagonObject p;
```

and so forth - in total about 25 such objects. Importantly, for each response object only one of these shape objects will be instantiated - the rest will be null.

Each of these specific shapes have a child element of the same class: BaseShape, which contains the fields and methods I need to map. Ex:

```
BaseShape base = response.getShapeSelect.getTriangleObject().getBaseShape();
```

So: I need to identify the ShapeSelect element that isn't null and grab the getBaseShape from that element 1) without using a long series of if statements and 2) in a way that our sonarQube scanner won't complain about.

My current plan is to use reflect to iterate across the fields of ShapeSelect until I find the non-null shape, then iterate over the methods looking for a method name that matches getBaseShape... I will report back on this, but I've been informed that it will probably run afoul of sonarQube. and I'm struggling to think of another way to accomplish this.

Comment: Wouldn’t it make more sense to have a superclass `ShapeObject` with a `getBaseShape` method? You could then avoid having so many different objects attached to each instance (since only one is being instantiated anyway) and instead just say, for example, `ShapeOject shape = new TriangleObject();`. Each child could override `getBaseShape` with its own unique implementation.

Comment: If you’re set on using reflection, you shouldn’t need to iterate over methods. It’s already designed in a way such that `getBaseShape` has the same method signature, so once you’ve found the non-null shape `object`, you can simply say `Method baseGet = object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(“getBaseShape”);` and then invoke it on `object`.

Comment: @CalvinP. It certainly would - or my thought was at least an interface, since they all already implement the getBaseShape() method, but this is a soap service we don't own - we import the response classes from gradle and they're not editable.

Comment: @CalvinP. thanks for the reflection tip! I'm not married to it, but I'm struggling to think of alternatives. Will let you know.